# cURL on MAMP not working but the same script works on server with Apache

Tags: php, curl, mamp

I have written php script that is login in to the site goes to the specific tab and pulls xlsx file.

The script was written and tested on MAMP and then mover to production server (Apache).
It still works on production server but exactly the same script does not work on MAMP (localhost).

What changed is:
current MAMP 5.6 previous was older. I am also using MacOS Catalina (new computer).

I checked firewall and tested on different networks etc.
I am not able to find problem.

Any suggestions please?

Update:
I do not get any error it just returns nothing.

Functions that I use to make a cURL call:

```
      $curl = curl_init($url);

      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $login_request_headers);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_jar_location);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_jar_location);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, $post);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, $get);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, $return_transfer);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, $follow_acction);

      return $result = curl_exec($curl);
      curl_close($curl);

    }

    public function request_post($url, $login_request_headers, $post, $get, $follow_acction, $return_transfer, $cookie_jar_location, $post_data) {

      $curl = curl_init($url);

      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $login_request_headers);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_jar_location);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_jar_location);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_data));
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, $post);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, $get);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, $return_transfer);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, $follow_acction);

      return $result = curl_exec($curl);
      curl_close($curl);

    }
```

Code to make the call:

```
//------call to login url------
  $site_url1 = "https://app.xyz.com/";
  $login_request_headers1 = [
    'Host: app.xyz.com',
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0',
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'DNT: 1',
    'Connection: keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1'
  ];

  $functions->request_get($site_url1, $login_request_headers1, 0, 1, 0, 0, $cookie_jar_location);

  $cookie_file_content1 = file_get_contents($cookie_jar_location);
  $strlen = strlen($cookie_file_content1);
  $cake_php = trim(substr($cookie_file_content1, $strlen-27));

//------call to POST login process------
  $site_url2 = "https://app.xyz.com/";
  $login_post_array = array("_method" => "POST", "data[User][username]" => SC_USER, "data[User][password]" => SC_PASS);

  $login_request_headers2 = [
    'Host: app.xyz.com',
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0',
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Referer: https://app.xyz.com/',
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length: '.strlen(http_build_query($login_post_array)),
    'DNT: 1',
    'Connection: keep-alive',
    'Cookie: CAKEPHP='.$cake_php,
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1'
  ];

  $functions->request_post($site_url2, $login_request_headers2, 1, 0, 0, 0, $cookie_jar_location, $login_post_array);

//------call to GET client site ()------
  $site_url4 = "https://clients.xyz.com/";

  $login_request_headers4 = [
    'Host: clients.xyz.com',
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0',
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Referer: https://app.xyz.com/',
    'DNT: 1',
    'Connection: keep-alive',
    'Cookie: CAKEPHP='.$cake_php.'; loggedIn[username]=test%40email.com; loggedIn[password]=testpassword',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1'
  ];

  $functions->request_get($site_url4, $login_request_headers4, 0, 1, 0, 0, $cookie_jar_location);
```

Comment: Can you post the *actual* error message here, stack trace, something? `Not working` is a given.

Comment: Sorry I didn't attach the code since t is working on Linux server and is not working on my local computer with MAMP. Thanks

Comment: Guys anyone please :). Is it possible that it is related to the browser I use on local machine? I spent 2 days on this and I do not understand why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your php script.
the problem is related to MAMP configuration

You have to send the request to an IP not to local address (ex. example.local)

Go to MAMP -> select your server -> From IP address ( * is selected by default ), choose an IP Address -> Set the Port number to be any number.

For example if MAMP gives you an IP address: 192.168.2.44 and you set the port to be 3344, you have to use it like this:

`$site_url1 = "http://192.168.2.44:3344";`

**ALSO PLEASE NOTE THAT:**

> You have to disable MAMP SSL if you enabled it.
> because it will not work with MAMP SSL